# How to copy from one folder all content (include subdirs) to distination?

Tags: c++

I am new in c++, but I thought it should be pretty simple actually it doesn't.

What I need to do is copy all content of one dir to another destination, but not just copy I need to make implementation of progress for this I need to know entire amount of files that going to be copied and progress of coping.

For example I have such structure

```
1) myfolder -> foo.txt
2) myfolder -> a -> foo1.txt
3) myfolder -> a -> b -> foo2.txt
```

I wrote such copy implementation for this

```
    /*static*/ void Utils::copy_files(std::string const & path_from,
        std::string const & path_to,
        TCallback progress_callback)
    {
        std::vector<std::string> paths_copy_from;
        std::vector<std::string> paths_copy_to;
        std::vector<std::string> tmp_final_dist;
        std::vector<std::string> path_to_inner_dirs;
        std::vector<std::string> paths = get_file_names_by_ext(path_from, "");

        if (progress_callback != nullptr)
        {
            progress_callback(0, 0);
        }

        separate_path_to_files_paht_to_folders(paths, tmp_final_dist, path_to_inner_dirs);

        for each(std::string tmp_dest in tmp_final_dist)
        {
            std::string file_name = base_name<std::string>(tmp_dest);
            std::string full_file_name = path_to + "\\" + file_name;
            paths_copy_to.push_back(full_file_name);
            paths_copy_from.push_back(tmp_dest);
        }

        tmp_final_dist.clear();

        for each(std::string tmp_dir in path_to_inner_dirs)
        {
            std::string dir_name = base_name<std::string>(tmp_dir);
            fs::create_directories(path_to + "\\" + dir_name);
            tmp_final_dist = get_file_names_by_ext(tmp_dir, "");

            for each(std::string tmp_files in tmp_final_dist)
            {
                std::string file_name = base_name<std::string>(tmp_files);
                std::string full_path_dest = path_to + "\\" + dir_name + "\\" + file_name;
                paths_copy_to.push_back(full_path_dest);
                paths_copy_from.push_back(tmp_files);
            }

            tmp_final_dist.clear();
        }

        tmp_final_dist.clear();

        //Actually these sizes always should be equal
        int length = min(static_cast<int>(paths_copy_from.size()), static_cast<int>(paths_copy_to.size()));

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            std::ifstream  src(paths_copy_from[i], std::ios::binary);
            std::ofstream  dst(paths_copy_to[i], std::ios::binary);

            dst << src.rdbuf();

            src.close();
            dst.close();

            if (progress_callback != nullptr)
            {
                progress_callback(length, i + 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

But because it is not a recursive I can copy just first to cases (mentioned above), what I can't copy is such structure `myfolder -> a -> b -> foo2.txt`, because here I have 2 inner layers.

About the solution I understand that I can add in my code one more `for` loop in order to iterate one more layer, but it is not what I am looking for, because tomorrow it could be +3 more layers and I will be need to add a lot of `for` loop interactions.

I need to find some kind of recursive solution where it does not matter how many layer I need to copy and also I need to know entire amount of file to be copied and copy progress.

Comment: Was I out of town when "`for each(std::string tmp_dest in tmp_final_dist)`" became valid C++ code?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem is probably worth a read.

Answer (score 0):

C++17 helps a lot. The below code (which I've written in 4.5 minutes and it's not tested) should give an idea of *one* possible solution:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

void copy (const std::string& from, const std::string& to, long actualCopy);

int main()
{
    auto iterator = std::filesystem::directory_iterator("/tmp/source");
    int count = std::count_if (begin(iterator), end(iterator), [](auto& entry) { 
        return (entry.is_regular_file() || entry.is_directory());
    });
    long actualCopy = 0;
    copy ("/tmp/source", "/tmp/dest", actualCopy);
    return 0;
}

void copy (const std::string& from, const std::string& to, long actualCopy)
{
    for(auto& p: std::filesystem::directory_iterator(from))
    {
        std::filesystem::copy(p, to);
        ++actualCopy;
    }
}
```